# Creating Select queries inside a query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, distinct, max

How can I display a distinct Field1 and a Field2 that contains the max value for field2?

For example, from the left table get the right table:

```
| Field1 | Field2 |        | Field1 | Field2 |
--------------------       -------------------
|  A     |  1     |        |  A     |  3     |
|  A     |  2     |        |  B     |  2     |
|  A     |  3     |        |  C     |  4     |
|  B     |  1     |        -------------------
|  B     |  2     |
|  C     |  1     |
|  C     |  2     |
|  C     |  3     |
|  C     |  4     |
--------------------
```

I'm a student yet and still a newbie in MySQL :)

Comment: your sample data shows the max for field2, not field1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select field1, max(field2) as maxf2
from table
group by field1
```